# Is there an application that generates an HTML form from a PDF?

Tags: html, forms, pdf, field, auto-generate

Is there an application out there that Generates an HTML form from a PDF file?  Also, it would need to generate the HTML form so that it would be able to submit to the PDF to fill out the fields inside the PDF.

PDF is not so good at validation and it's just a kluge interface to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your full requirements but [docudesk](http://www.docudesk.com/deskUNPDF_Professional_PDF-to-Word-Converter_2.shtml?gclid=CLv21oqHmZgCFRwDagoddmh2Aw) does this conversion as well as a number of others.

Adobe also have an online conversion [tool](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/access_onlinetools.html) that does this.